# Auth::attempt returns false when credentials are true

Tags: php, laravel

I have spent countless hours on this. Looked through the internet and cannot find a solution. The data is being passed through the form but will not authenticate with the database. The password is hashed upon registration also.
I have dumped the inputs and the credentials are being posted but will authenticate through the database. Any help is appreciated Thanks in advance!

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/login', function() {
return view('pages.login');
});
Route::get('/register', function() {
return view('pages.register');
});

Route::post('/register_action', [
'uses' => 'RegisterController@store',
'as' => 'signup'
]);
Route::post('/login_action', [
'uses' => 'LoginController@LogIn',
'as' => 'signin'
]);
Route::get('/dashboard', [
'uses' => 'RegisterController@getDashboard',
'as' => 'dashboard'
]);
```

**Login Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use Input;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
public function LogIn(Request $request) {
    $data = array(
        'email' => Input::get('useremail'),
        'password' => Input::get('userpass'),
    );
    dd($data);

    if(Auth::attempt($data)) {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }else {
        echo "Fail";
    }
}
}
```

**Register Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Input;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
public function getDashboard() {
    return view('pages.dashboard');
}

public function store(Request $request) {
    $username = $request['username'];
    $email = $request['email'];
    $first_name = $request['userfname'];
    $last_name = $request['userlname'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $email;
    $user->username = $username;
    $user->firstname = $first_name;
    $user->lastname = $last_name;
    $user->password = $password;

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('dashboard');

}

}
```

Comment: are you hashing the password?

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din You mean on register or login? I'm hashing on register,  $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

Comment: you have to do the same with login, please try it and post what you get.

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din I did this on login 'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('userpass')), and this on the registration controller, $password = Hash::make($request['password']); . I also included the hash in the top of the page. I tested dd($data), It gets hashed but still doesn't authenticate.

Comment: just to test, please remove the hashing from both login and register, then  recreate new user, then try to login with his credentials

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din I have removed all hashing, the password is in database unhashed, when i try to authenticate it still fails.

Comment: please post your User class

Comment: `Auth::attempt` uses `Hash::check` so You've to change hashing in registration procedure: `$password = Hash::make($request['password']);` , make a user and test again

Comment: Sorry guys, feel really stupid i had this in my User class,  public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->UserEmail;
    } . Just removed it and it works, I have literally spent 3 hours on this.

Comment: Can you please post the result of the dd you have used?

Comment: xD, good job @Bailee

Answer (score 0):

You should check your database migration.Password hushing needs at least 120 char.